# How can I convert an mp4 file to a m2v file using FFMPEG that is compatible with Windows Media Player?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I tried doing this but Windows says the file isn't playable. Playing it in VLC does work.

> ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -f mpeg -vcodec mpeg2video out.m2v

Comment: Try `-f vob out.mpg` although your WMP may need external codecs.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Media Player uses DirectShow, which is a system of filters connected together depending on what is fed into them.  If you want to play any format using Windows Media Player, it would be best to install a set of free open-source DirectShow filters known collectively as "LAV Filters", written and maintained by Nevcairiel.  Its latest installer release can be found on its Github releases page, here: https://github.com/Nevcairiel/LAVFilters/releases

However, if you're targeting default Windows installations, one of the highest-quality lossy codecs that Windows supports with its default DirectShow filters is Windows Media Video.  Here's how to transcode a Windows Media Video file conveniently with ffmpeg using Windows Media Video 8.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -q:a 2 -q:v 2 -vcodec wmv2 -acodec wmav2 output.wmv
```

There is a later version of Windows Media Video, called Windows Media Video 9, but FFmpeg doesn't support encoding Windows Media Video 9; only decoding.  For encoding that, you would be more likely to find success using a Microsoft tool.

I have one final note I'd like to include.  Ideally, unless your source video is lossless, you shouldn't be transcoding video to a lossy format such as Windows Media Video 8 if you can help it.  That introduces [generational loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss), which is a serious problem for archived video.  Instead, try to ensure your target playback system can play the original lossy-codec-encoded video or make sure you're encoding your lossy video from a lossless source.